# MediaElement position doesn't change

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I want to use `MediaElement` to play music, and when music played to some position, do some action. The code is like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement1.Play();
    game_pose_poller.RunWorkerAsync(); // game_pose_poller is a BackgroundWorker object
    button1.IsEnabled = false;
}

private void game_pose_poller_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (mediaElement1.Position >= sometime)
        {
            // do something
```

However I found the program did nothing at all. When debugging I found that `mediaElement1.Position` is always zero. Why is it always zero even after `Play()` called? `mediaElement1.Source` is an mp3 file which included as resource in project, and `LoadedBehavior` is Manual(or the `Play()` raise exception).

Comment: I found my computer's audio must be configured improperly, when I open the mp3 outside, no music at all too. But the sound icon in task tray seems normal. Is it the reason that Position doesn't change?

Comment: Sure - if it doesn't play, position doesn't change. Try another file!

Comment: to JeffRSon: When I open the file in Media Player, the position does change, just no sound. I don't think no sound itself should be the key problem

Comment: You cannot know how Media Player determines position. Have you tried another file?

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar some times ago using a `DispatchTimer` instead of a `BackgroundWorker`. This is how I've got it to work:

```
private DispatcherTimer positionTimer;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a timer that will check your condition (every second for example)
    positionTimer= new DispatcherTimer();
    positionTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    positionTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(positionTimerTick);
    positionTimer.Start();

    mediaElement1.Play();
    button1.IsEnabled = false;
}

void positionTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mediaElement1.Position.TotalSeconds >= sometime)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `DispatcherTimer` actually multi-thread, or just a tick event starter? Unfortunately timer is not likely to be useful to me, because I want to do something real-time just when the position passed some time. If using timer I have to assign `Interval` quite a small duration, and I think it will cause performance problems and/or duplicate tick events.

Comment: If you set the `Interval` value to 500 or even 250 milliseconds, your users won't notice any delay before your _"do something"_ action after the `sometime` threshold is met... Regarding the possible performance issue you mention, the use of a timer here should require less CPU than your current `while(true)` loop. HTH